# What is the geometric meaning of the equation for a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

**Context:**

I am working through George Polya's book, *Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning.*

Let $P$ be a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $ax+by+cz=d$ where $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are constant real numbers.

**My question:**

What is the geometric significance and/or meaning of the constants $a,b,c,d$? What do they imply about the position and orientation of the plane in  $\mathbb{R}^3$?

**Attempted solution:**

I see that, for a vector $(x,y,z)$ in the plane, it is required that $(a,b,c) \cdot (x,y,z) = |(a,b,c)||(x,y,z)|\cos(\theta)=d$. This seems to imply that varying $d$ and keeping $a,b,c$ constant might affect the "orientation," $\theta$, but then again $(x,y,z)$ can vary.

When $d=0$ and $(a,b,c),(x,y,z) \neq \vec{0}$, we have $\theta=\pi/2$, which implies that any vector in plane $P$ is always perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$.

On the other hand, if we consider a plane parallel to the $xy$ plane, $0x+0y+z=d,$ then it seems that $d$ determines how far along the z-axis the plane is.

At any rate, these are my scrambled thoughts so far. Could anyone help me see the bigger picture here?

Answer (score 2):

When $d=0$, we have $ax+by+cz=(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z)=0$ which is satisfied by vectors $(x,y,z)$ orthogonal to the fixed vector $(a,b,c)$.  Nonzero $d$ has the effect of shifting this plane in some direction.  For example you could say it is shifted in the x direction by $ d/a$: $ax+by+cz=d \Leftrightarrow a(x-d/a)+by+cz=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Is there a good way of defining the "orientation" of a plane, say in terms of several angles or with respect to the $x,y,z$ axes?

Comment: $(a,b,c)$ tells you all you need to know about how the plane is angled, it points out of the surface.  You could write this vector in spherical coordinates if you prefer, which would give the angles relative to the x,y,z axes.  Those formulas can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions